# Python anaconda Jupyter error: cannot import name 'TypeVarTuple' from 'typing_extensions

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.9

I am using python 3.9 with anaconda, in a custom environment. The fact that I am using an older version of python is to have tensorflow-2.5.3 and tensorflow-gpu-2.10.0 and tensorflow-io-0.18.0 be compatible with my cuda enabled Nvidia GTX-1060. I always run Jupyter lab by first going into anaconda prompt and activationg my virtual environment and then typing "Jupyter lab". Last time, everything ran perfectly, but while I ran a notebook cell with the code line"data = data.map(preprocess)", I received an error. I will provide the error shortly.

I closed all windows and restarted my windows 10 pro 22h2 x64 and tried to open Jypyter. the environment activated successfully, but when I typed "jupyter lab", I got the exact same error, which is:
(gpu_env) C:\Users\shahr>jupyter lab
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\shahr.conda\envs\gpu_env\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in *run_module_as_main
return *run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Users\shahr.conda\envs\gpu_env\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in *run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\shahr.conda\envs\gpu_env\Scripts\jupyter-lab.EXE_*main**.py", line 4, in 
File "C:\Users\shahr.conda\envs\gpu_env\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_*init**.py", line 8, in 
from .handlers.announcements import (
File "C:\Users\shahr.conda\envs\gpu_env\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\handlers\announcements.py", line 15, in 
from jupyterlab_server.translation_utils import translator
File "C:\Users\shahr.conda\envs\gpu_env\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server_*init**.py", line 6, in 
from .app import LabServerApp
File "C:\Users\shahr.conda\envs\gpu_env\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\app.py", line 10, in 
from jupyter_server.extension.application import ExtensionApp, ExtensionAppJinjaMixin
File "C:\Users\shahr.conda\envs\gpu_env\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\extension\application.py", line 16, in 
from jupyter_server.serverapp import ServerApp
File "C:\Users\shahr.conda\envs\gpu_env\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\serverapp.py", line 104, in 
from jupyter_server.services.contents.filemanager import (
File "C:\Users\shahr.conda\envs\gpu_env\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\services\contents\filemanager.py", line 21, in 
from anyio.to_thread import run_sync
File "C:\Users\shahr.conda\envs\gpu_env\lib\site-packages\anyio_*init*_.py", line 5, in 
from ._core._eventloop import current_time as current_time
File "C:\Users\shahr.conda\envs\gpu_env\lib\site-packages\anyio_core_eventloop.py", line 16, in 
from typing_extensions import TypeVarTuple, Unpack
ImportError: cannot import name 'TypeVarTuple' from 'typing_extensions' (C:\Users\shahr.conda\envs\gpu_env\lib\site-packages\typing_extensions.py)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your issue looks a lot like [this](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/9808#discussioncomment-6362992). Reading through how that was discussed, especially leading up to [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/9808#discussioncomment-6363353) might help you debug it. Minor related note: Please learn about posting code so the formatting is maintained using StackOverflow. In particular see about fenced code blocks [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/8508004).

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, and solved the issue by simply re-installing the Python package `jupyterlab` :

```bash
python3 -m pip uninstall -y jupyterlab
python3 -m pip install jupyterlab
```

But since you are using Conda, you could **reinstall Jupyter Lab in Conda** using the following:

```bash
conda remove jupyterlab
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab
```

---

References

1. Conda remove package : https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/remove.html
2. Conda install Jupyter Lab : https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html